# Using fetch in a parent component to pass to child components

Tags: reactjs

In my React application, I'm have trouble getting data returned from a `fetch` call in a parent component to the child components using the parent component's state.

I believe I'm following standard practices for this but it's not working.

Here is an excerpt of my parent component.

```
class TasksView extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            bus: null
        }

        this.handleBusLinkClicked = this.handleBusLinkClicked.bind(this);
        this.getBusDetailView = this.getBusDetailView.bind(this);
    }

{*/ called when a button is clicked /*}
    getBusDetailView(bus_pk) {
        const response =
            fetch("/bus_detail_view/" + bus_pk + "/")
                .then(response => response.json())
                .then(data => {
                        this.setState({
                            bus: data.vehicle
                        })
                    }
                );
    }
        render() {
             return (
                <ChargerBusModal bus={this.state.bus}/>
        )
    }
```

And here is an excerpt from my child component:

```
export class ChargerBusModal extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    }

    render() {
            return (
                <Modal show={this.props.show} className={"fade fade-scale charger-detail-modal zoomIn"}
                       id={"bus-detail-modal"}
                       tabIndex={"-1"}>
                    <Modal.Header closeButton>
                        <Modal.Title id={"modal-title"}> Bus Details
                        </Modal.Title>
                    </Modal.Header>
                    <Modal.Body id={"modalBody"}>
                            <BusDetailContext.Provider value={{
                                bus: this.props.bus}}>
                                <Row className={"align-items-center"}>
                                    <Col>
                                        <BusModalInformation/>
                                    </Col>
                                </Row>
                            </BusDetailContext.Provider>

                    </Modal.Body>
                    <Modal.Footer>
                        <Button variant={"secondary"} dataDismiss={"modal"} onClick={this.props.onHide}>Close</Button>
                        <Button variant={"primary"}> Save Changes </Button>
                    </Modal.Footer>
                </Modal>
            )
        }
    }
}
```

The issue is that when `getBusDetailView(bus_pk)` is called, and `this.state.bus` is set, `this.props.bus` in the child component is always null. I would expect it to be the value of the parent component's `this.state.bus`, but it's not. I confirmed that `data.vehicle` is not null.

Do you have any idea about what's going on?

Comment: Hmm your code definitely looks right. Have you tried using the React Developer Extension tool? This helps you inspect all state and props of a component.

Comment: where are you calling `getBusDetailView`?

Comment: I haven't used the extension tool yet, but I will.

I'm calling `getBusDetailView` in the parent component.

Comment: Could you share the code for the button that's triggering getBusDetailView?

Comment: ```
 <DepotTasksTable django_urls={django_urls}
                                         handleBusLinkClicked={this.handleBusLinkClicked}/>
```
and 
```
handleBusLinkClicked(evt) {
        let bus_pk = evt.target.getAttribute('class');
        this.getBusDetailView(bus_pk);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should add a '.catch' to your fetch, are you sure that the request is responding correctly?

```js
getBusDetailView(bus_pk) {
        const response =
            fetch("/bus_detail_view/" + bus_pk + "/")
                .then(response => response.json())
                .then(data => {
                        this.setState({
                            bus: data.vehicle
                        })
                    }
                ).catch(err => {
                   handleError(err)
               });
    }
```

Comment: I can confirm that the request is responding correctly, as I'm logging it.

Answer (score 0):

`this.props.state.bus` - have you tried this?

I know this is more than a year old; however, I am a beginner and have been facing a similar issue (passing state from parent to child component) when I found this question. In my case, on the child-component I had to use `this.props.state` & then the relevant object or element within the parent's state.

Moderators: Please edit or remove as appropriate.